# Raspberry pi 3 RFID RC522 Card UID is not same with USB RFID Reader

Tags: python, pi-3b+, python-3, rfid, nfc

I'm working with RFID RC522 using Raspberrypi 3B+. I'm following https://github.com/mxgxw/MFRC522-python this package and works like a charm. I can able to read the data from the card, able to write as well.

the problem is, this package is returing the card data as Array of strings.

```
 # Print UID
        print "Card read UID: %s,%s,%s,%s" % (uid[0], uid[1], uid[2], uid[3])  <== Here
```

The value looks like  : **185,113,174,85** and I'm concatinating this array into a single string and storing it in db for further functionalities.

Now, I expecting to get the same Uid from the card by using [USB based RFID Reader 13.56Mhz](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B07LGXNVTY/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1) . But Unfortunately, the value I'm getting is not same.

The value USB RFID Reader returns **1437495737**

How to rectify this. I need to get the same value for both RFID RC522 and USB based RFID Reader.

***Component Details:***

- RC522 RFID - [link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01CSTW0IA)
- 1K RFID 13.56Mhz PVC Smart Card
- USB Sensor Reader 14443A Proximity 13.56Mhz RFID Card Reader

Comment: This question doesn't seem to have anything to do with Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 2):

The value `1437495737` is in hex `55ae71b9`, or in little endian notation `b9 71 ae 55` while the integers `185 113 174 85` are in hex also `b9 71 ae 55`.

So you get the same value, just in different representation.

Comment: thanks for the solution. It works... but I have some other doubts to clarify..